# Получить элементы входящие в каждую коллекцию с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
class Entry
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
class Entry2
{
    public Entry2()
    {
        this.Enrties = new HashSet<Entry>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Entry> Enrties {get; set;}
}

List<Entry2> list; // содержит N количество элементов Entry2
```

Как получить элементы типа Entry, входящие в каждый Entry2? То есть если не содержится хотя бы в одном Entry2, то не попадает в итоговую коллекцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если решать в лоб то можно так:

```
List<Entry2> list = new List<Entry2>
{
  new Entry2 { Enrties = new List<Entry> { new Entry(1, "") } },
  new Entry2 { Enrties = new List<Entry> { new Entry(1, "") } },
  new Entry2 { Enrties = new List<Entry> { new Entry(1, "") } },
  new Entry2 { Enrties = new List<Entry> { new Entry(1, "2"), new Entry(2, "") } }
};

List<Entry> e2 = new List<Entry>();


foreach (var entry2 in list)
{
  foreach (var entity in entry2.Enrties)
  {
    if (list.TrueForAll(x => x.Enrties.Contains(entity)))
    {
      e2.Add(entity);
    }
  }
}

foreach (var entry2 in e2)
{
  Console.WriteLine(entry2);
}
```

Это решение будет работать если Вы в своих классах переопределите `Equals` и `GetHashCode`